# Divide the screen in to three different sizes

Tags: android-layout

In my application screen, there are two listviews say L1(filled with data D1) and L2(filled with data D2)and one button at the bottom of screen.

Conditions to display the lists:

```
if(show D1){

  //Display L1 list in the middle of screen and button at the bottom of screen.
  //Hide L2

}
if(show D2){

  //Display L2 list in the middle of screen and button at the bottom of screen.
  //Hide L1

}

if(show D1 && D2){

    if(D1>=D2){

        //Display L1 and L2 lists in the middle of screen and 
        //button at the bottom of screen.

    }else if(D1<D2){

        //Display L1 and L2 lists in the middle of screen and 
        //button at the bottom of screen.

    }
}
```

By using below layout, it shows everything correctly while displaying both the list at a time. But when showing L1, it covers the whole screen and overlaps the button and when showing L2, when data are few it displays correctly but button come upward just below the list instead of bottom of the screen.
layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background_main" 
    >

  <LinearLayout 
      android:id="@+id/layout1"
      android:layout_weight="1" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSubHeadingW"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="18dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/lbl1"
            android:textColor="@color/BlueViolet"
            android:textStyle="bold" style="@style/style_text"
            /> 

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"    
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

       />
      </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout2"
       android:layout_weight="1" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSubHeadingT"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="18dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/lbl2"
            android:textColor="@color/BlueViolet"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:visibility="gone" style="@style/style_text"
             /> 

      <ListView
        android:id="@+id/l2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"    
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
       />
    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnrControls"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dip"
        android:background="@drawable/top_portrait"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="3dip"
         >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_text_selector"
            android:text="@string/lbl_ok"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
           android:layout_gravity="center" style="@style/style_text"
           /> 

         </LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: make parent layout as relative layout..

Comment: M S Gadag if parent layout would be relative then weight property will not work for child layouts

Comment: use below to child layouts n in ur codeing with layout params adjust it..